# How to sort strings with integers by numeric ordering?

Tags: r, regex, sorting

I have a column in a `data.table` full of strings in the format string+integer. e.g.

```
string1, string2, string3, string4, string5,
```

When I use `sort()`, I put these strings in the wrong order.

```
string1, string10, string11, string12, string13, ..., string2, string20, 
string21, string22, string23, ....
```

How would I sort these to be in the order

```
string01, string02, string03, string04, strin0g5, ... , string10,, string11, 
string12, etc.
```

One method could be to add a `0` to each integer `<10`, `1-9`?
I suspect you would extract the string with `str_extract(dt$string_column, "[a-z]+")` and then add a `0` to each single-digit integer...somehow with `sprintf()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can remove the characters that are not numbers to do the `sort`ing

```
dt[order(as.integer(gsub("\\D+", "", col1)))]
```

Comment: What would be the difference of using `sort()` and `order()` here? It appears sorts leads to the same errors

Comment: The other problem I'm having with this: there are two strings which are labeled `stringX` and `stringZ`. These do not have integers, and should be put last. The above `as.integer()` will result in `NA`s if I don't somehow exclude these

Comment: @ShanZhengYang  Sorry, in your post you didn't mention all these things and the reproducible example was incomplete

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `str_extract` of `stringr` package to obtain the digits and `order` according to that

```
x = c("string1","string3","stringZ","string2","stringX","string10")
library(stringr)
c(x[grepl("\\d+",x)][order(as.integer(str_extract(x[grepl("\\d+",x)],"\\d+")))], 
   sort(x[!grepl("\\d+",x)]))
#[1] "string1"  "string2"  "string3"  "string10" "stringX"  "stringZ"
```

Comment: (Apologies for not mentioning this in the original question) This approach would work, except for one problem: here are two strings which are labeled stringX and stringZ. These do not have integers, and should be put last. The above as.integer() will result in NAs if I don't somehow exclude these

Answer (score 1):

You could go for `mixedsort` in `gtools`:

```
vec <- c("string1", "string10", "string11", "string12", "string13","string2", 
         "string20", "string21", "string22", "string23")

library(gtools)
mixedsort(vec)

#[1] "string1"  "string2"  "string10" "string11" "string12" "string13"
# "string20" "string21" "string22" "string23"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is something like below:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

  xstring <- data.table(x = c("string1","string11","string2",'string10',"stringx"))
  extracts <- str_extract(xstring$x,"(?<=string)(\\d*)")
  y_string <- ifelse(nchar(extracts)==2 | extracts=="",extracts,paste0("0",extracts))
  fin_string <- str_replace(xstring$x,"(?<=string)(\\d*)",y_string)
  sort(fin_string)
```

**Output:**

```
> sort(fin_string)
[1] "string01" "string02" "string10" "string11"
[5] "stringx"
```